# JavaMailSenderImpl doesn't use "mail.from" property from mail session

Tags: java, spring, email

I want to send a mail with a [`From`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2) header, but I don't want to set the `From` header  in the [`SimpleMailMessage`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html). I want to use the default configured with [`mail.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html) property for the [`javax.mail.Session`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html) (defined in `context.xml`).

Java's [`MimeMessage#setFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setFrom()) method supports that feature:

> Set the RFC 822 "From" header field using the value of the InternetAddress.getLocalAddress method.

But [`JavaMailSenderImpl`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html) doesn't use the property.

Tomcat's `context.xml`:

```xml
<Resource name="mail" type="javax.mail.Session" mail.debug="true"
        mail.smtp.host="mail.mycompany.com" mail.from="no-reply@mycompany.com"/>
```

Spring's `beans.xml`:

```xml
<bean id="mailSession" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/mail" />
</bean>

<bean id="JavaMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="session" ref="mailSession" />
</bean>
```

My service:

```
@Named
public class MailService {

    @Inject
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void send() {

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo("customer@company.com");
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setText("Test message body");

        javaMailSender().send(message);
    }
}
```

Log:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.mycompany.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 mail.mycompany.com ESMTP ready.
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.mycompany.com", port: 25

EHLO dev.mycompany.com
250-mail.mycompany.com Hello dev.mycompany.com [x.x.x.x]
250-SIZE 41943040
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "41943040"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<no-reply@mycompany.com>
250 OK
RCPT TO:<customer.company.com>
250 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   customer@company.com
DATA
354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2016 21:45:10 +0100 (CET)
To: customer@company.com
Message-ID: <1838762963.0.1481575510043@mycompany.com>
Subject: Test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test message body
.
250 OK id=1cGXTB-0007La-35
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT
221 mail.mycompany.com closing connection
```

The message has no `From` header.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Why Spring doesn't use the `From` header from mail session?

Comment: Hello! Did you find solution for this problem?

Comment: @mohax It is too long ago, I can't remember. But I didn't write an answer, so I guess, I didn't find a way.

Comment: OK, thanks. Maybe there is issue with DKIM. Tomorrow I'll try to sign email as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13833098/3212712) and write about results)

Answer (score 0):

From this link: http://springframework-user.narkive.com/wbF105Ma/simplemailmessage-and-date-header

> SimpleMailMessage is more or less the least common denominator of COS' and JavaMail's mail sending capabilities. Actually, it should be possible to set the date header with COS too; it's just that there is no explicit method for it in the COS MailMessage class. So we might provide date header support for SimpleMailMessage in a future point release.
>
> For the time being, you'll have to work with the JavaMailSender interface and JavaMail's MimeMessage class. With the MimeMessageHelper class that Spring provides, it should be easy enough to populate a MimeMessage in a SimpleMailMessage-style fashion. (See MimeMessageHelper's javadoc for details.) Of course, MimeMessage is much more powerful: It supports attachements, text encoding, etc.

I search and found those. which one you try it :

1:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = //get message from wherever
mimeMessage.addHeader("From", "me@mail.com");
```

2:

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
 message.setFrom("me@mail.com");
```

Comment: Your update sets the `From` header on the message, that's not what I want, I want to use the `From` header configured in mail session (don't call a setter on the message with the value).

Comment: @dur ok. so this code not working : JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("From", "a@b.com");
sender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);

Comment: It creates a new session instead of using the existing one. The session is in JNDI, my implementation doesn't know the properties.

Comment: @dur I don't know much about JNDI but you can't get session from JNDI and set properties and back again to JNDI?

Comment: I could do that, but it is real ugly.